# JHipster - warnings on new project generation

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

I'm just dipping my toes into JHipster and I'm finding that I'm getting lots of warnings upon generating a new project. They all seem to center around this "source-map" item.

```
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
```

I'm getting 27 lines of warnings with differing version numbers.

The project still builds successfully and runs.

What is going on here?

TY

Answer (score 5):

This is how yarn/npm resolve version conflicts between transitive dependencies, see [doc on dependency versioning](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-versions/)

Some dependencies require an old version of source-map package but JHipster team has found that only 0.6.1 works (see [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7031)) so they forced it in package.json in [`resolutions` property](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) until the other project release a new version. Yarn applies the resolution but complains because according to semantic versioning rules version 0.6.1 could break dependencies that require ^0.5.6 but it's only a guess.

You can find what's going on in details by inspecting `yarn.lock` and looking for source-map.